# Open Visual Studio project on MAC OS X

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos

I have a c++ project in Visual Studio, and I need to run that project on MAC OS X computers. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) Can be used to open and manipulate Visual Studio project on a Mac.
It can however only open `.csproj` files, not the legacy `.vcproj`. You can convert your old project to a compatible one, using [Visual Studio Conversion Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As you are working with C++, you are however free to use any IDE or editor you like. As long as loosing your project metadata files isn't a problem, you can just open the files in Xcode, TextMate, Sublime Editor or any editor of choice.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it's several years after asking this question, there is a possibility at last.

You can now install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on Mac and work with C++. [Here's how](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/24/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/) you can do it.

Comment: the 2nd link is for windows... the question specifically asks for mac os x

Answer (score -1):

There are SOME things you can do with Visual Studio Projects / Solutions on a Mac if you use Expression Studio.